# Display PDF file saved without extension in HTML object

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have a jQuery-UI popup which displays a variety of file types, including `image/jpeg` and `application/pdf`. The files have been saved without file extensions, and the file type is extracted from a database along with the file and passed to the app. I am displaying the PDF files in an HTML object, as follows:

```
if(fileType == 'jpg'){
    $('#viewerPanel').append('<img id="photo" src="' + file + '" />');
} else if (fileType == 'pdf'){
    $('#viewerPanel').append('<object data="' + file + '" type="application/pdf"></object>');
} else {
    $('#viewerPanel').append("Error! Unknown file type.");
}
```

This works fine for images and also correctly displays the `.pdf` file in IE11, however does not display correctly in my normal browser (Chrome).

Why does Chrome appear to ignore object type of `application/pdf` and is there something that can be done to remedy?

Edit: After reading some of the responses, I have checked on my normal browser (Chrome) and on IE11. It seems to display correctly in IE11 but not in Chrome. I have edited question above to reflect this.

Comment: @Stacked: thanks for your edit, but please use `code` ticks only on things that are clearly plain `code`, and `not` for regular `file` names and common acronyms such as "HTML".

Comment: What's the exact problem? Browser ignores `type="application/pdf"` or `fileType` is never `pdf`?

Comment: Thanks for the question Alvaro. The problem is that Chrome browser appears to ignore `type=application/pdf`.